# Express/AwsServerlessExpress/lambda/Secrets Manager - Exporting a Variable from a function -

Tags: amazon-web-services, express, aws-lambda, aws-secrets-manager

> Outline: Im attempting to port an express application to lambda using
> AWS Serverless Express, and I need to access Secrets Manager which
> stores credentials for MongoDB Atlas.
>
> Problem:  I have successfully retrieved my secret, however I cannot
> 'export' the secret for the remainder of the AWS Serverless Express
> application to use.
>
> What I have tried: parsing and updating environment variables
> modules.export.variableName (trying to export just the variable with
> the secret) modules.export.functionName (trying to export the entire
> function) return to an array (returning the results of the function to
> an array and calling from the array)
>
> Application Structure: lambda.js server.js /db/db.js controllers:
> there are 6 controllers in tota

lambda.js

```
'use strict'
const awsServerlessExpress = require('aws-serverless-express');
const app = require('./server');
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
require('dotenv').config();
const secretsManager = new AWS.SecretsManager({
region: 'us-east-1' });
const AWS_SECRET = process.env.AWS_SECRET;

let server;
let uri
var password
module.exports.uri3;
let uri2;

const createServer = async (callback) => {
const secret = await secretsManager.getSecretValue({SecretId: AWS_SECRET}).promise();

const secretBackup = JSON.parse(secret.SecretString)
   
Object.assign(process.env, JSON.parse(secret.SecretString));

module.exports.exporteduserName = secretBackup.username;
console.log('undernasdnfkasdf ' + this.exporteduserName) //This returns the correct value
password = secretBackup.password;
//console.log('this is what is stored in userName ' + userName)
console.log('this is what is stored in password ' + password) //This returns the correct value

uri2 = `mongodb+srv://${process.env.username}:${process.env.password}@cluster0.3jrug.mongodb.net/lamb?retryWrites=true&w=majority`; //This returns the correct value

module.exports.uri3 = uri2

console.log(uri2) 

server = awsServerlessExpress.createServer(app, null, binaryMimeTypes)
return server 

}

console.log('this is uri3 ' + this.uri3) //undefined

console.log('outside function ' + this.exporteduserName) //undefined
const binaryMimeTypes = [
  'application/javascript',
  'application/json',
  'application/octet-stream',
  'application/xml',
  'font/eot',
  'font/opentype',
  'font/otf',
  'image/jpeg',
  'image/png',
  'image/svg+xml',
  'text/comma-separated-values',
  'text/css',
  'text/html',
  'text/javascript',
  'text/plain',
  'text/text',
  'text/xml'
]
```

> I suspect my problem is here (below)- however I dont know fully what this
> code does. It seems to resolve the promise function and then set
> server to the createServer function with the SecretId.  why it is
> using this variable I'm not sure.

```
exports.handler = (event, context) => {
    Promise.resolve(server || createServer({SecretId: AWS_SECRET}, )).then((server) => {
    awsServerlessExpress.proxy(server, event, context);
    //console.log('this is what i have stored ' + process.env.AWS_SECRET);
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I managed to solve this issue and wanted to update it in the event that someone else may have this question.

The following documents Lambda 'best practices'.  In the link - they largely provide the format that should be used with using exports.handler
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/best-practices.html

There is a caveat however - because Im using AWS Serverless Express - it requires the creation of Promise.resolve create server event.  Due to this - you CANNOT use a promise function from inside the AWS Serverless Express exports.handler function.  This is because it already contains a Promise.resolve - so it just causes confusion if there are two promises.

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    Promise.resolve(server || createServer({SecretId: AWS_SECRET})).then((server) => {
        awsServerlessExpress.proxy(server, event, context);
        context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;
        var uri2 = `mongodb+srv://${process.env.username}:${process.env.password}@clusterX.XYYYYY.mongodb.net/lamb?retryWrites=true&w=majority`;
        var serverjstest = app.abetatestfunc (uri2);
        var dbfiletest = dbfile.dbfiletest (uri2);
      
    });


};
```

In my case - since Im using Express, I have many different *.js files.  In order to execute the functions - I have to module.exports the JS files as you can see above (dbfile.debfiletest(uri2)).  After that - I need to put my new pseudo function over top of the existing code, also with the uri2 input/variable. ie:

```
function abetatestfunc(uri2) {
    console.log('this is a test call from within server.js to see if we can get uri2 here ' + uri2)
    uri = uri2
    console.log('server.js value of uri ' + uri)

//your code goes here

}
```

In this manner - the function will be invoked with exports.handler gets called by the api gateway.

Hope that helps.  Im sure there are 100 different ways to make it nicer/better/run better - but Im not there yet.  Im just at the 'lets make it functional' stage.